# Is it possible to change the Job for existing Stream Analytics Module

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-edge

I deployed a new Stream Analytics Job and want to replace it in already created ASA module with its own Job.

But I see only an interface for updating the initial job with 
`Module outdated - click here to update` and `Update ASA Module` which on click generates a JSON with update properties for the old job.

Is it possible to  replace it with a new one or I should create a new module ?

Answer (score 0):

To change the job for your existing Steam Analytics Module on IoT Edge, you don't have to create a new module. Here are the steps:

- Create a new ASA job / modify the existing job
- Click on **Update ASA Module**
- Deploy the new job